# Why isn't this htaccess code blocking a specified IP?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a large htaccess file for my site. One of the IPs I'm trying to block is 27.153.228.56

Despite my htaccess, I still see 27.153.228.56 showing up in my latest visitor logs.

Is there something wrong with my htaccess that's allowing this IP to access the site?

There are many more IPs blocked but this is an abbreviated version:

`# Protect from spam bots`

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.garagehangover.com* [OR]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$`

`RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]`

`</IfModule>`

`# Begin IP blocking #`

`Order Allow,Deny`

`deny from 27.153.228.56`

`# End IP blocking #`

`#Begin Bad Bot Blocking`

`BrowserMatchNoCase yandex bad_bot`

`Deny from env=bad_bot`

`# End Bad Bot Blocking`

`Allow from all`

Answer (score 1):

`Order Deny,Allow`

And remove `Allow from all`

This will process all the deny rules, and if none match, allow the request.

Also, generally you would put these rules before the `RewriteEngine on` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me. But you could try to block a range of IPs like this...

```
deny from 27.153.228.0/255.255.255.0
```

or this

```
deny from 27.153.0.0/255.255.0.0
```